# On React Select using isMulti prop

Tags: reactjs, react-select

[image]
When isMulti is passed, the data returned is an array, when an item from the selected values is cleared, how would you get the value that was cleared?

From the screenshot, when the "x" button is clicked, how would you get the value selected?

I'm expecting to have a prop name something like "onClear" or so, so I can get the value cleared

Comment: found a fix... the onChange handler 

const handleSelectChange = (selectedOption, { option, removedValue }) => {
}


The `removedValue` has the label and value that was removed